# How to get custom table value Acumatica

Tags: c#, asp.net, acumatica

Hi i am having a hard time inheriting my custom table to my dac and making a selector here is my custom table Branded.cs

```
  [Serializable]
  public class Branded : IBqlTable
  {
    #region BrandID
    [PXDBInt(IsKey = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Brand ID")]
    public virtual int? BrandID { get; set; }
    public abstract class brandID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<brandID> { }
    #endregion

    #region Brand
    [PXDBString(InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Brand")]
    public virtual string Brand { get; set; }
    public abstract class brand : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<brand> { }
    #endregion
}
```

then here is my custom dac that i want to make a selector with

```
public class InventoryItemExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem>
    {


        #region UsrCategory
        [PXDBString(100)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName="Category")]

        public virtual string UsrCategory { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrCategory : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrCategory> { }
        #endregion

        #region UsrBrand
        [PXDBString(100)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName="Brand")]
        //red
        [PXSelector(
            typeof(Search<Branded.brand>),
                typeof(Branded.brandID),
                typeof(Branded.brand))]
        public virtual string UsrBrand { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrBrand : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrBrand> { }
        #endregion
```

How can i inherit the custom table on my dac to make a selector when i join them together i get

> An unhandled exception has occurred in the function 'MoveNext'. Please
>   see the trace log for more details.

[image]

Thank you for helping in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume since the BrandID is the key you want to store the key in the table but display the Brand value (using an ID/CD configuration). If this is true then you will want your UsrBrand in InventoryItemExt to be an Int and use the selector like this:

```
[PXDBInt]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Brand")]
[PXSelector(
            typeof(Search<Branded.brandID>),
            SubstituteKey = typeof(Branded.brand))]
public virtual int? UsrBrand { get; set; }
public abstract class usrBrand : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<usrBrand> { }
```

Also to skip the need to call out the columns in the selector if you set the visibility on the ui field attribute in your main DAC to SelectorVisible. All Columns marked with SelectorVisible will show in the selector ordered in the the order they appear in the dac. Also don't forget to include the string size.

```
[PXDBString(100, InputMask = "")]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Brand", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
public virtual string Brand { get; set; }
```

If this is not the case then you should have trace details as the error you posted indicates. Check there for more details and post the full error. It could be something unrelated to your DAC configuration.

Comment: Hi Brendan i had set the visibility now how can i call it now. Thanks

Comment: as off now my dac still cant see Branded.cs

Answer (score 0):

```
 #region UsrBrand
    [PXDBString(100)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="Brand")]
    //red
    [PXSelector(
        typeof(Search<Branded.brand>),new Type[]
         {
            typeof(Branded.brandID),
            typeof(Branded.brand))]
         }
    public virtual string UsrBrand { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrBrand : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrBrand> { }
    #endregion
```

Comment: Hi Vardan how can i set a reference to my branded my dac cannot see my branded.cs

Answer (score 0):

I got it now thanks. I realized that i have a code and a dac and that is making two table os i have to remove one and it worked perfectly thank you everyone